# How to remove microseconds in django DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

Hi people I have a datetimefield in my projects Model

the original value is the below:

2021-06-15 21:39:06.842317
after using

```
datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

this is the result:

2021-06-15 21:39:06.000000

the thing is after using the formatted code the result is this: 2021-06-15 21:39:06

but after inserting it, it added .000000 in the end. Does it have to do with DateTimeField itself?

I just rerun it just now and I see this warning:

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField AttendanceTbl. start_date received a naive datetime (2021-06-15 21:47:55) while time zone support is active. warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the issue, `datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` returns `2021-06-15 14:56:43` for me in Python 3.9.0. I don't see any `.000000` append to the end

Comment: yes sir, tried printing the result after reformatting the date and it's correct but after inserting it in the MySQL workbench the displayed value has .000000 in the end.

Comment: @Strobon what is the problem with the extra zeros? That is just how it is stored in the database...

Comment: coz when I insert a data directly through workbench sql, it wasn't like that. no zeros added, just a clean date. but in sql code it has..